# If one column value is >= 1/3 of another column value input text into another column

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert, mamp

I have a table called membership. One column is called amount_paid and the other is called valid_membership.
I have another table called m_type with  a column called price.
The linking clause is WHERE membership.type_id = m_type.type_id

I want a trigger before insert on the membership table to check if amount paid is >= 1/2 of price. If it is greater i want 1 to be placed in valid_membership else if it isn't true then 0 to be placed in valid_membership.

Just having a little trouble with the correct syntax,
This is what i have tried already--

```
DELIMITER
 //
CREATE TRIGGER valid_membership
    BEFORE INSERT ON membership
    FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
        IF (NEW.amount_paid >= 1/2 price) THEN
    SET valid_membership = '1' ELSE '0'
    WHERE membership.type_id = m_type.type_id
  END IF;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Please edit your question to include your best attempt, even if it doesn't work or even compile. It's not only what this site expects, but also clearly communicates the intention of your code.

Comment: Thanks for advice, only new to site so just learning the rules.

Comment: The title and code say “1/3”, but the text of the question says “1/2”. Please edit to make everything consistent (I assumed “1/3” in my answer)

Comment: thanks, updated now to half

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1/3 price` should coded as `price / 3`, but even better you could use plain SQL:

```
update membership set
valid_membership = (
   select amount_paid
   from price
   where membership.type_id = m_type.type_id
) >= price / 3
```

which can be executed as a plain update query, to both test the query and also backfill existing data.

For the trigger:

```
set new.valid_membership = (
   select amount_paid
   from price
   where new.type_id = m_type.type_id
) >= price / 3
```

This does use a small “trick” special to MySQL: In MySQL, `true` is `1` and `false` is `0`.

Comment: Where about would i fit this in within my original trigger?, Stuck on where i would insert the 1 and 0 into valid_membership

Comment: @gary as I said, the result of a boolean expression such as `x >= y` is `1` if it’s true and `0` if it’s false.

Comment: Thanks figured it out there, Thanks for response anyway.